# Точка в конце прямой речи или без таки неё?

Tags: пунктуация

Совки (от слова *сова*, а не *совок*), как правильно? Я думаю, 1-й.

`1. Мой папа, по имени Петрушончик, сказал-таки: «У меня есть пятнадцать руб.».`

`2. Мой папа, по имени Петрушончик, сказал-таки: «У меня есть пятнадцать руб.»`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точка в таком случае нужна, см. ["Грамоту.ру"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20291879).

**Вопрос № 291879**

> Здравствуйте. Ставится ли точка после цитаты, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит сокращённое слово, например: «„... и т. д.“.»?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Точка после кавычек ставится: ...и т. д.".

У [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178) даже есть правило на этот случай.

> **Точка** повторяется после закрывающих кавычек, если перед ними она употреблена в качестве знака, обозначающего сокращение слова: В объявлении было сказано: *«Появилась в продаже дачная мебель: столы, стулья, диваны и т. д.».*

Comment: Вот это я понимаю – помощник так помощник!